# react children render props unit test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

i have two components, one is Parent and the other is the Kid passed as renderProp

```
export class Kid extends Component {
  render() {
    const { age, name } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="kid">
        <span className="age">age: {age}</span>, name: {name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    age: 20,
    name: "the name"
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children({ age: this.state.age, name: this.state.name })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="parent">
      <Parent>{({ age, name }) => <Kid age={age} name={name} />}</Parent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

how can I make sure the `Kid` has the correct props with unit test

```
describe("<App />", () => {
  it("Should render Kid", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    console.log(wrapper.debug());

    // pass
    expect(wrapper.find(Parent).exists()).toBe(true);

    // fails
    expect(wrapper.find(Kid).exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(wrapper.find(Parent).children().find(Kid).exists()).toBe(true);

    // fails
    const kid1 = wrapper
      .find(Parent)
      .renderProp("children", { age: 5, name: "a" });
    expect(kid1.prop("age")).toEqual(5);
    expect(kid1.hasClass("kid")).toBe(true);

    // fails
    const kid2 = wrapper.find(Parent).prop("children")({ age: 5, name: "a" });
    expect(kid2.prop("age")).toEqual(5);
  });
});
```

Here is the sandbox example
https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-children-function-hcvzz?file=/src/App.test.js:0-884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two tests fail because you're not using `renderProp` here. The second two tests fail because `renderProp` ([docs](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/renderProp.html#renderproppropnameargs--shallowwrapper)) takes a prop name and returns a function that takes the render-prop arguments, so you'll need to pass the object in a separate function application:

```
const kid1 = wrapper.find(Parent).renderProp("children")({ age: 5, name: "a" });
```

The test on `kid1.hasClass("kid")` will still fail though as `Kid` itself is not actually rendered, since you're using `shallow`. And the test on `kid2` will pass if you replace `.prop("children")` with `renderProp("children")`, but then it's just the same as `kid1`.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-children-function-forked-50tcg?file=/src/App.test.js)

Comment: fantastic, thank you. Do you know how can I render `Kid` to make this test `kid1.hasClass("kid")` pass?

Comment: I'd probably do this in a unit test for `Kid` instead, but you can do it here with `kid1.dive().hasClass("kid")`.